# OpenCV. "Error: Assertion failed" when getting pixel value

Tags: c++, windows, opencv, type-conversion

I try to compile this code for Windows 10.

[pic2svg](https://github.com/LeoLovemary/pic2svg/blob/master/src/main.cpp)

A couple things have changed in this lib for my OS but problem raises on 93 line:

```
uint32_t p = pic.at<uint32_t>(y, x);
```

when we try to take the whole pixel as 4 byte. This is error:

```
OpenCV(4.1.0-dev) Error: Assertion failed (((0x28442211 >>
((traits::Depth<_Tp>::value) & ((1 << 3) - 1))*4) & 15) ==
elemSize1()) in cv::Mat::at, file C:\OPENCV\install\include
opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 1145
```

I fixed it by converting in such a strange way:

```
Vec4b tmp = pic.at<Vec4b>(y, x);
uint32_t p = (tmp[0] << 24) | (tmp[1] << 16) | (tmp[2] << 8) | tmp[3];
```

But problem comes in below code when we try to get pixel as uint32_t again. How to fix it?

Comment: opencv does not have / support an `uint32` type for cv::Mat. please check `pi.type()` and report back

Comment: @berak pic.type() equal 24.

Comment: @berak Is this CV_8UC4? What does it mean?

Comment: `8UC4` means that `Vec4b` is an acceptable type to access a Mat of this type. -- `uint32_t` is probably also acceptable because it has the same width (32 bits/4 bytes)... or used to be, before that type check was implemented. you can take the byte values from the Vec4b and compose them as you did in the last code snippet of your post.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz and berak , this helps! "Before that type check was implemented" I use 4.10. Christoph make it as answer, I'll mark it. :)